# Why when I print an element of an array it starts with undefined and then the numbers that I insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Why when I print an element of an array it starts with undefined and then the numbers that I insert. I even tried to cosnole.log(search[j]) and its exactly what I want. But for some reason I think the first += that I do is undefined.

```
function new_vid(){
let x=1;
console.log("################################################################");
for(let i=0; i<search1.length; i++){
    if(search1[i]=="s" && search1[i+1]=="n" && search1[i+2]=="i" && search1[i+3]=="p" && search1[i+4]=="p" && search1[i+5]=="e" && search1[i+6]=="t"){
        for(let j=i+36; j<i+46; j++){
            console.log(search1[j]);
            dates[x]+=search1[j];
        }
        x++; 
    }
}
console.log(dates[0]);
console.log(dates[1]);

console.log("##################################################################");
}
```

the output is:

undefined2021-08-04

undefined2021-08-01

Comment: _"...and then the numbers that I insert"_ - `... += ...` is not the correct way to "insert" something in an empty array.

Comment: And this is not a [mcve] -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `let x=1;` - Arrays in JS are zero-based. `dates[0]` will be unassigned

Comment: @Andreasa  What is the correct way? And sorry I am a bit messed up ... Coming from c++ and I am confused

Comment: [Indexed collections - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#array_object)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do this work on a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dates[x]` is `undefined` before the first insert. And `dates[x] += search1[j]` in principle does the following:

```
dates[x] = dates[x] + search1[j]
```

But `undefined + "foo"` results in `undefinedfoo` in JS. Use

```
dates[x] = (dates[x] || "") + search1[j]
```

This way `dates[x] || ""` will return the empty string if `dates[x]` is undefined, and thus concatenate the empty string with `search1[j]`

But as you say you are coming from a c++ background, I wonder a little bit about your careless usage of indexes without any bound-checking. And your algorithm will go out of bounds, because you are iterating your index `i` all over the `search1` array, and then access an index `i+1`, `i+2` or even `i+36`.

This will not crash in JS, but be aware that `search1[j]` will as well return `undefined` if the index `j` is out of bounds of your array, so you may need

```
dates[x] = (dates[x] || "") + (search1[j] || "")
```

as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `dates` is array, the 1st element basically is `undefined` since you haven't declared before.   ​

You can do the check before adding into the dates

```js
if(dates.length == x+1)
 ​dates.push(search1[j]);
else
 ​dates[x]+=search1[j];
```

If you are wondering about `push`, it's just the same mechanism as the function `push_back()` in C++ Vector.

One more thing is, this line of code will make you always find the `undefined` when you do the `console.log` in the next line.

```
for(let j=i+36; j<i+46; j++){
```

When it happen? It will happen if it's any possibility for the `search1` to contain the word **snippet** at the end of string, then the string will not have anything at the `i+36` or higher indexes.